# Calling save on a model in Ruby on Rails not actually saving it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-4.2

In my console I save models like this:

```
billy = Student.first
billy.name = 'Billy'
billy.save
```

Works as expected. However, after I call an `ApplicationMailer` in the console, the above mechanism no longer works :(

```
MyMailer.send_some_emails
billy.name = 'Jimmy'
billy.save # returns true
billy.save! # no exception thrown
billy.reload
billy.name # will return 'Billy', not 'Jimmy' as expected
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it will help to enable SQL logging and see if the correct data is sent to the database? `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`.

Comment: We actually do have SQL logging enabled and in the first case, we see the SQL `UPDATE` statement output. In the second case though, there is nothing sent to the database. We just see `begin transaction` followed immediately by `commit transaction`

Comment: Try these couple of things:
In pry `show-method billy.save` to make sure it's not redefined.

`billy.update_attributes(name: 'Jimmy')` to see if other persisting methods work.

Save another instance of this model.

Save an instance of another model.

Comment: @muistooshort - that SQL statement works and is only shown before sending the emails, that SQL statement is not sent for the saving after sending the emails

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this a couple of times.
It's always been a case of having set `attr_accessor` for that attribute in its respective model. Without seeing more of your code I can't tell you for sure, but I bet you have something like this.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name
  #code...
end
```

Check out the  [accepted answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12905103/rails-model-attr-accessor-attribute-not-saving) for more details. But essentially you need to remove the `attr_accessor :name` line.

Comment: I have a few `attr_accessor`s, but they're all for completely unrelated fields (having to do with devise). `name` is not referenced.